# cassandra long ordering is off for negative longs? or am I doing this wrong?

Tags: cassandra

I have the following few values I see in cassandra(realize, I AM putting various stuff in on purpose to see what happens).  NOTE: All the 8 byte values were longs and the other few were some strings.  The sort order appears to be fine for positive longs and even for the UTF8 strings as well.  The negative longs are at the very end of the list however!!!!

```
RowKey: 6d796f6e655f696e646578
=> (column=000000000000000a, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=0000000000000014, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=0000000000000028, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=000000000000003c, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=00000000000000c8, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=0000000000000154, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=00000000000001f4, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=0000000000000226, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=00000000000002bc, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=000000746bb814ee, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=30303030303030303030, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=61, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=617364667364, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=6565656565, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=657772776572657772657772, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=fffffffffffffe0c, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=ffffffffffffff38, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=ffffffffffffffd8, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
```

Now, if I tell cassandra to assume type long, the same row appears like this missing a bunch of columns(I really don't know why cassandra removed the negative columns????)...

```
RowKey: 6d796f6e655f696e646578
=> (column=10, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=20, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=40, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=60, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=200, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=340, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=500, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=550, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=700, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
=> (column=500023432430, value=, timestamp=1343228055671000)
```

Two questions:

1. Why is the negative longs now missing(all the other longs I see are correctly translated back)?
2. I understand that if there is only 8 bytes, you really need to store 2's complement, so the sort order is "going" to be wrong, so how do people typically deal with a column slice of -50 to +50 then?  Are they doing two slices, one at the begin and one at the end?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordering of columns is based on the column family's comparator. When you tell cassandra-cli to assume a certain type it only changes the way the columns are displayed, not the ordering.

Try creating a new column family with the comparator = LongType. This will sort your columns in the order you expect (LONG_MIN..LONG_MAX).

Comment: okay, great info, but then why is it not displaying the negative longs when I set it to display long?

Comment: hmmmm, still not right order after this command "assume time_indexes comparator as long;"  Maybe that is the key comparator, not the column name one?  What is the command for this?

Comment: drop/create fixes it, and negative now shows...not sure why negative stopped showing that one time..that was weird.

Comment: Note that your comment `maybe that is the key comparator` was probably wrong because keys (for "rows") are generally not sorted using the data content, but a hash key such as the content MD5. You have to change the default to avoid that behavior and it is a cluster setup which means it has to be setup at the time you create the cluster.